# Floating Action Button over Scrollview?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, algorithm

I'm revamping my app to follow look more "Material Design-ey", but have run into trouble with the FAB. I have a scrollview with two floating action buttons:

---

**When I scroll to the bottom, the FABs cover my content. I want to be able to scroll a little past the bottom so the FABs can be `align_parent_bottom` without overlapping anything:**

[image: Picture speaks a thousand words :)] (should be able to scroll a little more for FABs to be aligned below)

---

[image] (Before scrolling down)

How do I create extra space at the bottom of my app **after scrolling down to the max** for the FABs to rest?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#68d9cc">

    <ScrollView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#68d9cc">



    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/back"

            android:onClick="cancel"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Test example"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"

            android:text="textview:"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"

            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:elevation="9dp">

    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="textview"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:onClick="cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/done"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp"
        />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are aiming for Material Design as you mentioned, then putting those Floating Action Button like that are not encouraged. Either stack them on top of each other on the right, or have one where it will open multiple mini FAB on click.

An easy fix however I can think of here would be to add paddingBottom to your layout so it would have more "content" and it would scroll up more.

I would read this section if you haven't already.

https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#

Comment: How much paddingBottom should I add? It would never be exact based on different screen sizes, right?

Comment: Yep, different devices will have different dps. So what you could do is instead of a FAB height and weight be "wrap_content" you set it to 56 x 56dp (This is the default size mentioned in material design for FAB) and the paddingBottom will also be 56dp as well.